# Show elementarily that $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Gamma_1} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition, contour-integration

*Context:* I am trying to show that $\int_0^\infty x^{-1}\sin x dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$ using complex analysis, by first integrating $\oint_{\Gamma} z^{-1}e^{iz}$, where $\Gamma$ is a closed contour consisting of two portions of real axis $-R$ to $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ to $R$ and two semicircles $\Gamma_1(0,R)$ and $\Gamma_2(0,\epsilon)$.

I am almost done. I just need to show that $$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Gamma_1} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} = 0.$$

I don't need a rigorous proof. I am new to complex analysis and know almost no theorems. I just want to understand things "intuitively", if it's possible. So far, I know only Cauchy formula/theorem and residue theorem.

I found following solution, which I don't understand very well:

Integrate by parts $\int_{\Gamma_1} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} = \frac{e^{iz}}{iz}|_{-R}^{R} + \int_{\Gamma_1}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}dz$. The first turns out to be $\frac{2i}{R}\sin R \to 0$. Then absolute value of the integral is bounded by $\pi R \max_{\Gamma_1}{|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}|}\leq\frac{\pi}{R} \to 0$.

Why does it suffice to evalute at $R$ and $-R$? Why is the integral bounded by this?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how to put it well. The formula for integration by parts for path integrals is $$\int_\gamma f(z)g'(z)\,dz = f(\gamma(b))g(\gamma(b)) - f(\gamma(a))g(\gamma(a)) - \int_\gamma f'(z)g(z)\,dz,$$ if $[a,b]$ is the parameter interval of $\gamma$. If you plug in the definition of the path integral $$\int_\gamma h(z)\,dz = \int_a^b h(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)\,dt,$$ it reduces to the ordinary integration by parts for real intervals familiar from calculus. So the gist is: You evaluate at the two endpoints of the path. The path $\Gamma_1$ goes from $R$ to $-R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One uses here the inequalilty
$$\left|\int_\Gamma f(z)\,dz\right|\leq|\Gamma|\max\limits_{z\in\Gamma}|f(z)|$$
($|\Gamma|$ being the length of path $\Gamma$), which is almost obvious from the definition of integral of complex variable.

In your case $|\Gamma_1|=\pi R$ (half of a circle of radius $R$) and $|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}|=\frac{1}{|z|^2}=\frac{1}{R^2}$ for all $z\in\Gamma_1$, so $\max\limits_{z\in\Gamma_1}|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}|=\frac{1}{R^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $z=Re^{i\theta}$, $0\leq \theta\leq\pi $, $$\left| e^{i z}/z\right|\leq e^{-R}/R.$$
Use this to bound the original integral. No need for anything fancier.

Comment: This is false, for instance, with $z=R$ we get $|e^{iz}/z|=1/R$.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. Used the $\sin$ in the wrong way. Mathing from a cell phone is hard. Honest!