# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{2}{\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{-iz}}{z}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having some trouble with the following exercice:

> Let $R>0$ and consider the following curve in the complex plane: $\gamma _R:[0,\pi]\to \mathbb C$ given by $\gamma_R(t)=Re^{it}$. What is the value of: $$\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{2}{\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{-iz}}{z}dz$$

I tired evaluating this integral but I got such when I got to: $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{-iRe^{it}} dt$$

How can this be done?

Thank you

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3280965/42969. It is not the same, but closely related.

Comment: The problem is that this limit does not converge to 0, so founding an upper bound of the integral does nothing I think. @MartinR

Comment: A duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4482946).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} \, dz
$$
can be evaluated with Cauchy's integral formula or the residue theorem, it does not depend on $R$. Also
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} \, dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} \, dz + \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{-iz}}{z} \, dz
$$
and the first integral converges to zero for $R \to \infty$, see

- [Show elementarily that $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Gamma_1} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/877767/42969)  or
- [Complex integral on the semicircle with radius goes to infinity: $ \lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3280965/42969).

Combining these facts you can compute the desired limit.

Comment: If we always choose the ccw direction, then
$$\int_{|z| = R} \frac {e^{i z}} z dz =
\int_{\gamma_R} \frac {e^{i z}} z dz +
 \int_{\gamma_R} \frac {e^{-i z}} z dz.$$

Comment: @Maxim: You are right, I made an error in the $z \mapsto -z$ substitution, thanks.

Comment: why is $
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} \, dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} \, dz + \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{-iz}}{z} \, dz
$? Should't it be $
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} \, dz = - \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} \, dz + \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{-iz}}{z} \, dz
$?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães: You split the integral into one over the upper semicircle and one over the lower semicircle. The upper semicircle integral is $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z} \, dz$. In the lower semicircle integral you substitute $z \mapsto -z$, and get $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{-iz}}{z} \, dz$.

Comment: but if we substitute $z\mapsto -z$ then $\frac{e^{iz}}{z} \mapsto -\frac{e^{-iz}}{z}$

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães: $dz \mapsto -dz$ and $z \mapsto -z$, so the $(-1)$ factors cancel. Actually I had that wrong in the first version of my answer, and Maxim made me aware of the error.

Comment: That's true, I forgot about the dz. Thank you. Just one more thing: I asked my teacher if we could perform substitutions when computing complex integrals and he told me that that's not always possible but he didn't elaborate any further. Why is it valid in this case to substitute $z \mapsto -z$?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães: It is allowed if you take into account that the integration path changes. If $\gamma: [a, b]\to D \subset \Bbb C$ is a path and $\phi: D \to \Bbb C$ a differentiable function then $\Gamma = \phi \circ \gamma$ is a new path, and $\int_\Gamma h(w) dw = \int_\gamma h(\phi(z)) \phi'(z) dz$. In our example $\phi(z) = -z$.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much!